# rails wrong association with has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I tried to set up a basic association between users and projects:

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects, foreign_key: 'owner_id'
  has_many :project_members, through: :project_members
end
```

project.rb

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_members, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :project_members
end
```

project_member.rb

```
class ProjectMember < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
end
```

my project_members table:

```
+----+------------+---------+
| id | project_id | user_id |
+----+------------+---------+
|  1 |          1 |       1 |
|  2 |          2 |       1 |
+----+------------+---------+
```

and my project table:

```
+----+-------+----------+
| id | name  | owner_id |
+----+-------+----------+
|  1 | test1 |        1 |
|  2 | test2 |        2 |
+----+-------+----------+
```

why I get with

```
current_user.projects
```

only the projects where the projects.owner_id = current_user.id and not the projects where the user is member?

But I think it's the wrong side I tried to get the data I want.
I'm on /projects where the projects controller gets the data. 
I think I should use something like that:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /projects
  def index
    @projects = Project.all
  end
end
```

but how I can get only the projects where current_user.id is member of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should set that up a tiny bit different:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :owned_projects, class_name: "Project", foreign_key: 'owner_id', dependent: :restrict_with_error
  has_many :project_members, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :projects, through: :project_members
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_members, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :project_members

  belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User"
end
```

In order to get all the projects the current_user is a member of you can do:

```
current_user.projects
```

In order to get all the projects the current_user owns you can do:

```
current_user.owned_projects
```

Answer (score 3):

As an addition to `Kasper Johansen`'s answer, you may also wish to look into [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association):

[image]

The main reason you'd use this is because you're not using any extra attributes in your join model (which is your current setup).

If you want to keep it that way, you can do away with your join model by using the `has_and_belongs_to_many` association in place of `has_many :through`:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
end

#join table - projects_users

#app/models/project.rb
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

From the [docs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pYszRjH-R7Y):

> The simplest rule of thumb is that you should set up a `has_many
>   :through` relationship if you need to work with the relationship model
>   as an independent entity. If you don't need to do anything with the
>   relationship model, it may be simpler to set up a
>   `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship (though you'll need to remember
>   to create the joining table in the database).

---

In regards your original problem, you have to also remember that in order to get the data back from an associative model, you have to set up the associations that will be populated with that data.

You mention...

> why I get with `current_user.projects` only the projects where the `projects.owner_id = current_user.id`

... because you've set the *association* of `has_many :projects, foreign_key: 'owner_id'`

Rails is not magic - it has to take what associations you give it and populate the data in those methods accordingly:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :owned_projects, class_name: "Project", foreign_key: :owner_id
   has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
end

#app/models/project.rb
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

Hopefully gives you some more context to add to `Kasper`'s answer.

Comment: That is an incredibly good answer. Good job :-)

But be careful when choosing to go with "has_and_belongs_to_many". Here is a warning about it:

http://blog.flatironschool.com/why-you-dont-need-has-and-belongs-to-many/

Comment: Thanks bud. I use habtm on the simplest associations, beats having bullshit models like "post_category.rb" and "image_category.rb" all over your app. Nothing worse than looking at someone's models and seeing 20 when they could easily have 5